# Why don't we use trigonometric functions for the output neurons?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, activation-functions

Why don't we use a trigonometric function, such as $\tan(x)$, where $x$ is an element of the interval $[0,pi/2)$, instead of the sigmoid function for the output neurons (in the case of classification)?

Comment: Are you only interested in classification or also regression?

Comment: In classification. I'm curious as to why we fit the data using a sigmoid function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's true that if you use certain trigonometric functions, such as the tangent, you could have numerical problems (as suggested [in this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/22108/2444)), that's not the only reason for not using trigonometric functions.

Trigonometric functions are periodic. In general, we may not want to convert a non-periodic function to a periodic one. To be more concrete, let's suppose we use the sine function as the activation function of the output neurons of a neural network. Assuming only one input, if the input to any of those output neurons is $360k$, for any integer $k$, the result will always be $0$, but that may not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why the sigmoid function is used is because it 'does not blow up' since it is between 0 and 1 always. As for the relu it is used because it is computationally cheap and even resolves the problem of vanishing gradient(and hence used more often than sigmoid).

So a function like tan(x) will blow up for certain values of x. This can cause a problem of exploding gradients. So, I believe for this reason tan(x) cannot be a good non-linearity to be used.

As for any other function, it is more because of the results that we have gotten over the years and sigmoid and relu have been promising.