# Why is sine activation function not used frequently since we know from fourier transforms that sine functions can combine to fit any function?

Tags: neural-networks, activation-functions

Pretty much the title.
I'm no expert but from what I know, if you add up enough sine functions with proper amplitudes and frequencies you can get any function you want as a result. With that knowledge, wouldn't it make sense to have neuron's activation function be a sine function?

Comment: No it wouldn't. There are many considerations, like computational complexity, monotonicity, multivariate nature of data.

Comment: There was once [a similar question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/22100/2444), which I answered by saying that the sine is periodic, and that may not be desirable. Doesn't the Fourier transform assume that you have like complex coefficients or something? I don't recall anymore.